# Are American legends on topic and should there be a tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

My family tells a series of folklore tales. Specifically in this case:

- Bloody Bones
- The Welcome Stretcher
- Maul Tail

I am curious as to if they have a deeper seeded (seated?) origin.

If these tails exist outside of my family tree, I feel that they would be American Folklore, but no such tag exists.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, folklore is definitely on topic here. Please feel free to ask these questions at your convenience.

Whether a tag should exist is a potentially more tricky question. Conceptually speaking, tags should exist if they are useful. In this case, since most of our content concerns [native-american](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/native-american) mythology, a search for american or america would be inundated with those results instead of modern American folklore -  good example where tags would be helpful. On the other hand, other countries from the Americas (the continents) might well have a cause to object if the whole tag is appropriated for only the United States.

Thus, I suggest naming the tag [north-american-folklore](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/north-american-folklore), by way of analogy from [european-folklore](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-folklore).

In any case, you will be able to create new tags at 150 reputation.